# How to access runtime compiled type's field

Tags: c#, dynamic, codedom

I compile a class using CSharpCodeProvider from string and return the instance of compiled class as dynamic:

```
CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
CompilerResults compilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, myClassCode);
Assembly assembly = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly;
resultType = assembly.GetType("MyClass");
var res = resultType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).Invoke(new object[] {});
return (dynamic)res;
```

All compiles without errors and returns instance is what I need, but when I'm trying access some field of it I get an exception:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for MyInstancePublicField

As I think my mistake is using cast to dynamic type, but there is no any other way I've found to access fields which become known only at runtime.

Comment: Make it `public`, or use reflection.

Comment: MyInstancePublicField is public field

Comment: Make the type public too.

Comment: It helped me, thanks! You may write it as answer, to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `dynamic` will not allow you to use non-accessible members.

Since your type is defined in a different assembly, you need to make the type and the properties `public`.